# Joystick is working after loading new scene but if i go back to the first scene its not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a college student and just started making a game on Unity for the project but I'm having problems with the joystick.

1. First problem is the joystick is stuck in its last position when loading a new scene and
2. the second one is when I load a new scene and go to another scene I can still use the joystick but if I go back to the first scene the Joystick can drag but the player is not moving.

(I use the joystick script from the standard assets' CrossPlatformInput and modify it a bit).

here is the joystick script

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler
    {
        public enum AxisOption
        {
            // Options for which axes to use
            Both, // Use both
            OnlyHorizontal, // Only horizontal
            OnlyVertical // Only vertical
        }

        public int MovementRange = 100;
        public AxisOption axesToUse = AxisOption.Both; // The options for the axes that the still will use
        public string horizontalAxisName = "Horizontal"; // The name given to the horizontal axis for the cross platform input
        public string verticalAxisName = "Vertical"; // The name given to the vertical axis for the cross platform input

        Vector3 m_StartPos;
        bool m_UseX; // Toggle for using the x axis
        bool m_UseY; // Toggle for using the Y axis
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_HorizontalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_VerticalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input

        void OnEnable()
        {
            CreateVirtualAxes();
        }

        void Start()
        {
            m_StartPos = transform.position;

        }

        void UpdateVirtualAxes(Vector3 value)
        {
            var delta = m_StartPos - value;
            delta.y = -delta.y;
            delta /= MovementRange;
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Update(-delta.x);
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Update(delta.y);
            }
        }

        void CreateVirtualAxes()
        {
            // set axes to use
            m_UseX = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyHorizontal);
            m_UseY = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyVertical);

            // create new axes based on axes to use
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(horizontalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_HorizontalVirtualAxis);
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(verticalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_VerticalVirtualAxis);
            }
        }


        public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.zero;

            if (m_UseX)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.x - m_StartPos.x);
                //delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, - MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.x = delta;
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.y - m_StartPos.y);
                delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, -MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.y = delta;
            }
            //transform.position = new Vector3(m_StartPos.x + newPos.x, m_StartPos.y + newPos.y, m_StartPos.z + newPos.z);
            transform.position = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z), MovementRange) + m_StartPos;
            UpdateVirtualAxes(transform.position);
        }


        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
        {
            transform.position = m_StartPos;
            UpdateVirtualAxes(m_StartPos);
        }


        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data) { }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            // remove the joysticks from the cross platform input
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the player script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    //private int idle;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    private static bool playerExists;
    public string startPoint;
    Vector2 movement;

    void Start()
    {

        if (!playerExists) 
        {
            playerExists = true;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        }
        else 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //input
        movement.x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        // movements

        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    }



}
```

and is the load scene script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadNewArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string levelToLoad;
    public string exitPoint;
    private PlayerMovement thePlayer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>();
      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if(other.gameObject.name == "Player") 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
            thePlayer.startPoint = exitPoint;
        }
    
    }
}
```

I make the joystick that has the joystick script as a *child* of joystick background and make the joystick background a child of the player.

Comment: anyone who experience the same as me please help I really need to fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve those issues by simply removing the joystick background as a child of the player and manually adding it in each scene. However, if you know of another way to fix it, I would be grateful.